# Paint over top of label, not behind it in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

[image: Dial]

I am creating a simple gauge in Qt 4.7.4, and everything is working wonderfully. Except for the fact that, for the life of me, I cannot get the dial shape to paint over the text labels when it passes over them. It always paints it behind the label. I am just using a simple `drawpolygon()` method.

I'm thinking this has something to do about paint events? I am drawing everything inside a `QFrame` inside a `MainWindow`. I am using `QFrame`'s `paintEvent`.

Edit:
The QLabels are created on start up with new QLabel(this). They are only created once, and never touched again ( Similar to manually adding them on the Ui with Designer). The drawpolygon() is in the QFrame's Paint event.

"myclass.h"

```
    class gauge : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit gauge(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~gauge();
    void setValues(int req, int Limit, bool extra=false);

private:

    void drawDial();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);

};
```

"myclass.cpp"

```
void gauge::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e);


     drawDial();
    return;
}


void gauge::drawDial()
{


    QPainter Needle(this);
    Needle.save();
    Needle.setRenderHint(Needle.Antialiasing, true); // Needle was Staggered looking, This will make it smooth
    Needle.translate(centrePt); // Center of Widget
    Needle.drawEllipse(QPoint(0,0),10,10);
    Needle.restore();
    Needle.end();
}
```

Comment: Are you drawing the labels in that same method, or are they drawn somewhere else? Can you show the relevant parts?

Comment: Are you drawing the label or are they QLabels added to the layout?

Comment: @Mat The QLabels are created on start up with new QLabel(this). They are only created once, and never touched again ( Similar to manually adding them on the Ui with Designer). The drawpolygon() is in the QFrame's Paint event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the gauge widget and the QLabels are siblings, then you can move the gauge widget to the front by calling its [raise()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#raise) method.

If the QLabels are children of the gauge widget, on the other hand, then they will always display in front of it.  In that case you can either reorganize your widget hierarchy so that they are siblings instead, or you can get rid of the QLabels and simply call drawText() from your paintEvent() method instead (after drawDial() returns)

Comment: raise() method is not working, and I rotate the needle, how would I do the text without rotating that also?

Comment: draw the text outside of the save()/restore() pair, or rotate back before drawing the text

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that, but sounds computationally expensive, this will be on an embedded system. If I subclass QLabel, and call drawDial() method in my new QLabel, will the needle still behind the label?

Comment: If your QLabel subclass's paintEvent() calls up to QLabel::paintEvent() first, and then draws the dial afterwards, then the dial will be drawn over the text.  (If you're worried about efficiency you could cache the rendered text into a QPixmap and then just draw the QPixmap when necessary instead... but I wouldn't worry about that optimization unless/until you observe a performance problem)